# Simulating mouse down/click on multiple windows (4 windows)

Tags: c#

We have 4 3rd party applications that run on the same machine.

There are a few buttons that we need to manually click every single time on all 4 windows.

The windows are all the same size and never change positions.

How could we simulate a Mouse Click / Mouse Down on these windows? We can't use SetCursorPos/mouse_event since we want to "Simulate" a click and mouse drag in real time. A user's mouse cursor can't be moved, it has to emulate a click.

I can use Spy++ to get the necessary window handle/class, but I would like to know what needs to be sent to the window to make it work.

Comment: You can pinvoke PostMessage() to post the WM_LBUTTONDOWN/UP messages.  That usually works, as long as the app doesn't call GetCursorPos().

Comment: I have found this project really helpful for input simulation: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/. To simulate mouse events you'll need to download and build the latest source yourself. See this page for an explanation: http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/discussions/86530